# Ограничить доступ к треккеру в Redmine в рамках одного проекта

Tags: ruby, redmine

Есть один проект, в нем несколько трекеров.

Как некоторым участникам проекта (или участникам, или ролям) закрыть доступ к некоторым трекерам в рамках этого проекта (или сделать невидимым, или не давать создавать задачу в этом трекере)?
Это можно сделать стандартными средствами или нужно доработать?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант создать еще один проект, сделав текущий проект родительским (новый проект будет в него вложен). Можно открыть доступ к родительскому проекту и закрыть к подчиненному. При этом при наличии прав в родительском проекте будут все задачи, в том числе и подчиненного проекта.

Comment: Да, я это понял, но не понимаю как это на права для создания задач на определенные треккеры ограничит?